# Cómo se realiza una consulta INSERT INTO en MySQL desde un programa Java?

Tags: java, mysql, mysqlconnector

Estoy intentando hacer un programa Java que se conecta a una base de datos MySQL con el conector de MySQL para Java pero por algún motivo no se reflejan los cambios en la base de datos...

Este esel código de mi consulta

```
try {
        String query = "INSERT INTO `Auto` (`Placa`, `Marca`, `Modelo`, `Reparacion`) VALUES (`" + txtPlaca.getText() +"`+, `"+ txtMarca.getText() +"`, `" + txtModelo.getText() + "`, `" + txtReparacion.getText() + "`))";
        PreparedStatement preparedStmt = cn.prepareStatement(query);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(nuevoCliente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Estas son las variables que he inicializado al inicio del programa:

```
public class nuevoCliente extends javax.swing.JFrame {

Connection cn;
Statement st;
ResultSet rs;

public nuevoCliente() throws SQLException {
    initComponents();
    cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/tallerAutos?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "root", "");
}
```

Comment: btw se conecta y puedo consultar datos que haya introducido en la base de datos desde el gestor de la base de datos, pero no puedo introducirlos mediante una consulta desde mi programa Java

Comment: El código que nos compartes genera algún mensaje?, devuelve algún error?

Comment: @Aprendiz no, ninguno, eso es lo que me hace más difícil encontrar la solución

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás usando de manera incorrecta `prepareStatement()`, ya que esto no ejecuta la instrucción que tienes en la variable `query`, solo "prepara" la sentencia que se va a ejecutar:

De la siguiente manera, la sentencia que se está construyendo es mucho mejor de divisar y entender, los signos de pregunta simbolizan los valores que se están insertando, los cuales serán ingresados después, a la correspondiente posición.

Finalmente se debe de ejecutar la sentencia que se ha preparado.

```java
String query = "INSERT INTO `Auto` VALUES (?,?,?,?)"; // 4 posiciones
PreparedStatement preparedStmt = cn.prepareStatement(query);

preparedStmt.setString(1, txtPlaca.getText()); //primero la placa, posición 1
preparedStmt.setString(2, txtMarca.getText()); //Pasa la marca, posición 2
preparedStmt.setString(3, txtModelo.getText() );  //pasa el modelo, posición 3
preparedStmt.setString(4, txtReparacion.getText()); //pasa la reparación, posición 4

psInsertar.exequteUpdate(); // Se ejecuta la sentencia
```

Lo que falta en tu código es ejecutar la sentencia, es por eso que no te da ningún error, solo estás "preparando la sentencia", sin ejecutar nada.

---

También podrías prescindir del `preparedStatement` y hacerlo simplemente como un `statement` sin preparar previamente la `query`, insertando los datos como actualmente lo tienes en tu variable `query`:

```java
try {
        String query = "INSERT INTO `Auto` (`Placa`, `Marca`, `Modelo`, `Reparacion`) 
                        VALUES (`" + txtPlaca.getText() +"`+,
                                `"+ txtMarca.getText() +"`, 
                               `" + txtModelo.getText() + "`, 
                               `" + txtReparacion.getText() + "`)";
        ResultSet rs=sentencia.executeQuery(query);
} catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(nuevoCliente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Fuentes:

[Ejemplo con preparedStatement](http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=Ejemplo_con_preparedStatement)

[JDBC Prepared Statement y su manejo](https://www.arquitecturajava.com/jdbc-prepared-statement-y-su-manejo/)

Comment: Gracias maestro

Comment: Un gusto ayudar, te dejé de igual manera links con info relevante del tema, para que si mi explicación fue un poco enredada entendieras mejor :) PD: en ese caso maestra :o